# Is it possibile to add a google calendar to an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

I am trying to have section of my app which display a google calendar which will sync with event added to google calendar.
Basically my goal is to give to all users the possibility to check the events added from the app administrator.
So for example I add an event directly form calendar.google.com/calendar and all the app user can see it.
Is it possible to achieve it? 
If not with google do you know any other way to do so?
Thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google does not provide a Calendar component to directly integrate to your app.

What you should do is to use Google API to connect and fetch calendars events and then use your own or one of the open source calendar components to display those events. You can find open source calendar components [here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=calendar), chose one according to your needs.

Google gives an example of how to connect to those APIs [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/tree/master/Examples)

Comment: Thought so...thank you for your answer! I’ll implement my calendar and then try to fetch events from a google calendar!

Comment: I added links to calendar components you can use.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

So you want to implement an own calendar displaying just google events?

That's a bunch of work. You should give [this](https://github.com/arshinx/iOS-Google-Calendar-API) a try to access the google API or read their documentation. As far as I know, there is no ready to use solution for having a Google calendar within your app.

But to point you to the right direction:

1. have a look into the documentation
2. look for a third party calendar to implement
3. If the above mentioned SDK gives you a listener to events, go for it
4. if not, implement your own by constantly checking or a button for refresh
5. update the implemented calendar according to your needs with the new events

Happy coding!